# Pass data between 2 webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, web-part

I have a `ContentBySearchWebPart` where it will get all the sites that user has access within the site collection. At the same time, I need to show how many pending requests for each of these sites which are pending action from this user as well (just immediately right behind the site name).

I am able to get all the sites that user has access by using the `contentBySearchWebPart` but I am not able to get the number of pending requests for that site.

1. I am not sure can I achieve this using `ContentBySearchWebPart` as well? if yes, can someone please give me some guideline on how to do this.
2. If it is not achievable in `ContentBySearchWebPart`, then I am planning to create another web part (maybe a `ScriptEditorWebPart`) and place it after the `ContentBySearchWebPart` just to show the pending request. But now the problem is, I need to iterate through all the sites return in `ContentBySearchWebPart` and pass the site URL to the `ScriptEditorWebPart` in order to check for the pending request. can I pass the value from one web part to another?